# How do I write a code template for eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have some specific code that I need, to be able to have certain I/O stuff that I don't want to write every time, and I just want to be able to add a java class so that it already has that code in there, I tried doing :

```
/*
ID: my_id
PROG: ${filename}
LANG: JAVA
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class ${filename} {

    static class InputReader {
        private StringTokenizer st = null;
        private BufferedReader br = null;

        public InputReader(String fileName) throws Exception {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }

        public InputReader(InputStream in) {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in), 32768);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }

        public String next() {
            while (st == null || !st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                try {
                    st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
            return st.nextToken();
        }

        public int nextInt() {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String hostname = addr.getHostName();
        boolean isLocal = hostname.equals("paulpc");
        String location = null;
        InputReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        if (!isLocal) {
            location = ${filename}.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
            in = new InputReader(location + "/" + "${filename}.in");
            out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(location + "/" + "${filename}.out"));
        } else {
            in = new InputReader(System.in);
            out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        }
        solve(in, out);
        out.close();
    }

    public static void solve(InputReader in, PrintWriter out) {

    }
}
```

Basically this thing needs to be in xml, but I don't know how to write it properly, I thought writing ${filename} everywhere would do it, but it doesn't work. All in all, I want the name of the file to be written in places where I write "${filename}", how can I do it?

Comment: @user2277872 didn't help, eclipse itself says that it can't parse that xml file. Intellij makes this so simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a template variable like this:

```
public class ${cursor}${type:newName} {
    public ${type}() {
        // constructor
    }
}
```

Now if you use this as a template, both `type` occurrences will be updated by what you write when you edit it after template insertion.